# Passing Int* and double* from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to retrieve two arrays from C++ plugin to be used in C#.

The code is as follows:

C++

The function "funcplugin" has a void return type and I wish to return two single dimension array's of length 16 and 24.

```
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
void funcplugin(int* corners, double* points)
{
   corners = new int[16];
   points = new double[24];
   //code to compute and populate array values
}
```

C#

```
private IntPtr corners;
private IntPtr points;
private int size_corners =16;
private int size_points =24;

[DllImport ("native")]
private static extern void funcplugin(IntPtr corners, IntPtr points);

void call
{
   int[] first = new int[16];
   double[] second = new double[24];
   corners = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size_corners);
   points = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size_points);
   
   funcplugin(corners, points);

   Marshal.Copy(corners, first, 0, size_corners);
   Marshal.Copy(points, second, 0, size_points);

   for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("corners: " + first[i]);
        }
   for (int j=0; j<24; j++)
        {
            Debug.Log("points " + second[j]);
        }
   
   //code to use the array
   
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(corners);
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(points);

}
```

The Debug.Log statement is giving garbage values for the arrays. I am sure I am doing something wrong in retrieving the values.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to multiply the size by `Marshal.SizeOf<int>()` and `Marshal.SizeOf<double>()`, also you should put it all in a `try` with `FreeHGlobal` in the `finally`.  Why don't you just use standard marshaling instead: `private static extern void funcplugin(ref int[] corners, ref double[] points);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ code, the pointers are being passed in *by value*, so no matter what addresses the function sets them to point at, the caller will not be able to receive these addresses. To accomplish that, you would need to pass the pointers *by reference* or *by pointer*, eg:

```cpp
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
void funcplugin(int* &corners, double* &points)
{
   corners = new int[16];
   points = new double[24];
   //code to compute and populate array values
}
```

Or:

```cpp
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
void funcplugin(int** corners, double** points)
{
   *corners = new int[16];
   *points = new double[24];
   //code to compute and populate array values
}
```

Also, if the function allocates the arrays using any memory manager that the caller does not have direct access to (ie, via `new[]`), you will need to export a function to free the arrays using the same memory manager (ie, via `delete[]`) after the caller is done using them, eg:

eg:

```cpp
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
void funcpluginfree(int* corners, double* points)
{
   delete[] corners;
   delete[] points;
}
```

And then on the C# side, you can do this:

```cs
private int num_corners = 16;
private int num_points = 24;

[DllImport ("native")]
private static extern void funcplugin(out IntPtr corners, out IntPtr points);

[DllImport ("native")]
private static extern void funcpluginfree(IntPtr corners, IntPtr points);

void call
{
   int[] first = new int[num_corners];
   double[] second = new double[num_points];

   IntPtr corners;
   IntPtr points;
   
   funcplugin(out corners, out points);

   Marshal.Copy(corners, first, 0, num_corners);
   Marshal.Copy(points, second, 0, num_points);

   funcpluginfree(corners, points);

   for (int i = 0; i < num_corners; i++)
   {
       Debug.Log("corners: " + first[i]);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < num_points; j++)
   {
       Debug.Log("points " + second[j]);
   }
}
```

Now, that being said...

Your original C# code is allocating memory (but not allocating enough of it, BTW) to pass into the C++ code to fill in with data. In which case, there is no reason for the C++ code to also allocate its own memory as well. So, you can get rid of `new[]` inside of `funcplugin()`, and then there would be no need to export a function to call `delete[]`, eg:

C++

```cpp
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
void funcplugin(int* corners, double* points)
{
   //code to compute and populate array values
}
```

C#

```cs
private int num_corners = 16;
private int num_points = 24;

[DllImport ("native")]
private static extern void funcplugin(IntPtr corners, IntPtr points);

void call
{
   int[] first = new int[num_corners];
   double[] second = new double[num_points];

   IntPtr corners = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(num_corners * sizeof(int));
   IntPtr points = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(num_points * sizeof(double));
   
   funcplugin(corners, points);

   Marshal.Copy(corners, first, 0, num_corners);
   Marshal.Copy(points, second, 0, num_points);

   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(corners);
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(points);

   for (int i = 0; i < num_corners; i++)
   {
       Debug.Log("corners: " + first[i]);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < num_points; j++)
   {
       Debug.Log("points " + second[j]);
   }
}
```

Or, as @Charlieface mentioned in comments, you can use C#'s native [array marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays) (also [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays)) instead of allocating the memory manually, eg:

```cs
private int num_corners = 16;
private int num_points = 24;

[DllImport ("native")]
private static extern void funcplugin([In, Out] int[] corners, [In, Out] double[] points);

void call
{
   int[] first = new int[num_corners];
   double[] second = new double[num_points];
   
   funcplugin(first, second);

   for (int i = 0; i < num_corners; i++)
   {
       Debug.Log("corners: " + first[i]);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < num_points; j++)
   {
       Debug.Log("points " + second[j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou @Remy for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.